# Failed to Xposed Hook a class of defpackage package in a multidex apk

Tags: android, hook, android-multidex, xposed

It's a multidex apk.
I want to hook a method in the class defpackage.bky shown as following screenshot.

[image: Jadx screenshot]

[Jadx screenshot image link](http://www.site-digger.com/uploads/questions/mtwm_defpacket_bky.png)

1. I tried to hook Application.class "attach" method as following, but failed: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "defpackage.bky" on path".

   ```
       XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(Application.class, "attach", Context.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
           @Override
           protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
               ClassLoader cl = ((Context)param.args[0]).getClassLoader();
               Class<?> hookclass = null;

               try {
                   hookclass = cl.loadClass("defpackage.bky");
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("MtwmXposed", "寻找defpackage.bky报错", e);
                   hookclass = null;
               }
               if(hookclass != null) {
                   Log.i("MtwmXposed", "寻找defpackage.bky成功");
                   XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(hookclass, "a",
                           JSONObject.class,
                           new XC_MethodHook() {
                               @Override
                               protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                                   super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
                                   JSONObject shop_info = (JSONObject) param.args[0];
                                   Log.d("MtwmXposed", "From defpackage.bkt.a: " + shop_info.toString(2));
                               }
                           });
               }


           }
       });
   ```
2. I also tried to hook ClassLoader.class "getClass" method as following, but not found the defpackage.bky either.

   ```
      XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(ClassLoader.class, "loadClass", String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
           @Override
           protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
               super.afterHookedMethod(param);
               if (param.hasThrowable()) return;
               Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) param.getResult();
               String name = cls.getName();
               Log.d("MtwmXposed", "class name =  " + name);
               if (name.equals("defpackage.bky")) {
                   Log.i("MtwmXposed", "寻找defpackage.bky成功");
                   XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(cls, "a",
                           JSONObject.class,
                           new XC_MethodHook() {
                               @Override
                               protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                                   super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
                                   JSONObject shop_info = (JSONObject) param.args[0];
                                   Log.d("MtwmXposed", "From defpackage.bkt.a: " + shop_info.toString(2));
                               }
                           });
               }

           }
       });
   ```

Comment: me to . Are you solved this problem???